# Verizon says my bill has been paid, but no transaction on my card?

Tags: united-states, billing, online

So I paid my Verizon bill this Friday and they’re saying everything is okay, but nothing’s posted on my card and no money has been taken out? What’s happening here?

Comment: Have you asked Verizon why the payment hasn't shown up on your account?

Answer (score 2):

If you received a confirmation number or email or some other message, that is the proof that they were happy.

You should also be able to go back into the Verizon website and see that you submitted the payment and they generated your receipt.

It can take a few business days for the transaction to get back to the credit card or the bank. Depending on the time you submitted on Friday it might have been considered too late for Friday, and it could have been treated as a Saturday, or even a Monday transaction.

While I frequently see preliminary transactions for restaurants and gas stations on my credit card account, other transactions take a day or two to appear.

Comment: There’s a ‘payment history’ receipt or something.. i just don’t want them to change their mind and say i havent paid.. and it was autopay so I hope it was done early Friday,..ugh

Answer (score 1):

Friday was a bank holiday, so they would process it only on Monday. Which means you probably see it today = Tuesday. Check tonight.